# Could not insert new action connection: the line number to insert at (189) is not inside the container

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to drag an action from a button and keep receiving a strange error - "Could not insert new action connection: the line number to insert at (189) is not inside the container" 
What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Repo:
[(You can only run project on an actual device (I have iPhone 6s), since I use iPhone's camera)](https://github.com/Rudko/boo)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZkN0.png)

Comment: Weird error.  What happens if you try to insert at line 177?

Comment: I've cloned your project, everything is ok, i can create the action. If your git is exactly the same version that you are running, line 188 = scope of didPresstab function

Comment: @Mayke I believe it's an Xcode glitch. I've spent like several days trying to figure out what's the reason of this error. Anyway I was able to solve it. You just helped me to understand that it's a glitch, not an actual error. I dragged an action between accessoriesTabBarButton() and didPressTab() – Xcode placed it inside shoesTabBarButton() (this kind of things happened before). After that I just moved my new action to the very bottom of view controller file. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: I am getting this error after copying one view controller into a different storyboard, and then renaming its class. So when I have tried to make an outlet, I got this error. It seems that even if we set a new class, Xcode uses previous one to determine if we can do things (eg. like I did try to make an outlet).